# NameVirtualHost 12.345.67.89:443 has no VirtualHosts after enabling and disabling suexec module

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, apache-2.2, suexec

In the process of trying to enable suexec module I starting getting these warnings (when I restarted apache). I get them when suexec is enabled & disabled:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2
[Wed Oct 05 01:29:40 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost 12.345.67.89:443 has no VirtualHosts
... waiting [Wed Oct 05 01:29:41 2011] [warn] 12.345.67.89:443 has no VirtualHosts
...done.
```

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04, Apache2.2, PHP, MYSQL...

I'm running one site via https:// with a signed cert, ssl, etc, along with several other non-encrypted sites. This was previously working fine, but now (since I restarted the server after trying to enable suexec) I receive the above errors. If the *:443 virtual host is enabled, apache will not restart, and will not serve anything. If I disable the *:443 virtualhost, apache will *not* restart, and won't serve any of the domains I am hosting.

The only thing I messed with, except the suexec configuration (via command line), was the sites-enabled config file for the ssl-enabled domain, which looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin name@gmail.com
     ServerName mysite.com
     ServerAlias www.mysite.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/mysite.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
     SSLEngine On
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.com.crt
     ServerAdmin name@gmail.com
     ServerName mysite.com
     ServerAlias www.mysite.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/mysite.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /srv/www/mysite.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyway, I'm not sure what's going on here but I'm reluctant to dig too deep into the other apache / ssl configs since I didn't change anything there and everything was working before.

I'm stumped.

**EDIT**

Some more info:

/etc/apache2/ports.conf:

```
Listen 12.345.67.89:80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

NameVirtualHost 12.345.67.89:443
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` makes no mention of port 443

... nor does `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

Comment: `grep -lr "NameVirtualHost" /etc/apache2`?

Comment: @quanta Edited ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This **warning** comes up because you define a [`NameVirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) for `12.345.67.89:443` but there is no `<VirtualHost 12.345.67.89:443>`. So, change to `NameVirtualHost *:443`, it will go away.

Comment: This indeed solved the warning - thankyou... Apparently everything was still working ok under these settings. The fatal error was that I was missing an SSLCertificateKeyFile directive in my secure site's VirtualHost configuration. Thanks again!